# What's a positive word for "disruptive"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

When talking about disruptive business practices, we are speaking of things out of the ordinary or off the expected trajectory, which typically leads conventionally minded people to think it's a bad thing. However, in the case that the status quo is insufficient for the future, disruptive forces would be a good thing. Thoughts?

Comment: A sports metaphor that people frequently use to describe a positively disruptive innovation is "game-changing."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disruptive is often used in a positive light in the business sense that you are describing.

For example:

[*Disruptive innovation*](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptive_innovation) - The iPhone was a disruptive technological innovation that reinvented the smartphone market.

I agree that many will be tempted to assign a negative value to the argument if you begin with disruptive.  But, context should bear this usage out.

Otherwise, you can use terms like *reimagining*, *iconoclastic*, *revolutionary*, *etc.*. But, these tend to read like advertising copy.

**Radical technologic shift** carries a similar meaning without using the word disruptive.

Comment: Damn, David, foiled again. We should think about partnering on something.

Comment: @Jim Hahahahahahhahaha. Worse, I hit the rep cap before answering. So, it was for free.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Aside from the catch words, any ideas of a metaphor or analogy that could communicate this idea.

Comment: @Sailer unfortunately anything you use for a one word answer will smack of catch word. I would either use disruptive and explain its meaning, or just phrase around it with *radical shift* or *emerging technology*.

Answer (score 2):

Noting the OP's comment below, here are some other suggestions:

**[Revolutionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revolutionary?show=0&t=1394860277)**: causing or relating to a great or complete change. ([ref](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revolutionary)) Radically new or innovative; outside or beyond established procedure, principles, etc.: a revolutionary discovery.

**[Transformational](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transformation)** : causing a change or alteration, especially a radical one.

--
**[Disruptive innovation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptive_innovation)** is taken to have a positive effect.

Disruptive innovation is a breakout innovation that escapes from incremental changes that might ordinarily set the pace of advances in products and technology.

Development of the transistor or of the integrated circuit are examples of disruptive innovation. Internet development may have had (and still has the potential for more) a strong element of disruptive innovation

Comment: Thanks. But looking for something suggestive beyond the obvious. "taken to have a positive effect" depends entirely on how the word or statement is received by the listener. Simply looking to increase the odds of a positive reaction among a generally conservative and negative audience.

Comment: Got it. I'll Update.

Answer (score 0):

*Catalyst* does not have a negative connotation, and is less of a cliché than all the other suggestions ... (*you should avoid clichés like the plague*).